# not fetching data from database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here i have a list of same category names which comes under different parent category.when i fetch the data according to the id am getting result because id is different for all but when i fetch by category name am getting only the first results even though i have two same category names under different parent category..here is my category table

```
    id      category_name   parent_id
    8          men             0
    9          kids            0
    10       T-shirts          8
    11        Shirts           8
    12        Jeans            8
    13        Pants            8
    14        Shorts           8
    15        Tees             9
    16        Shirts           9
    17        Jeans            9
    18        Pants            9
```

Here am having shirts as the category name under different parent_id.when i select the id of 16-shirts am getting the value of of id 11-shirts because of the same category name.
Here is the controller am using

```
public function men_clothing_image($category=null)    
{   

    $category_id =$this->roxmodel->get_category_id($category);     
    $data['active_mn']='men_clothing';

    $data['men']=$this->roxmodel->get_category_by_parent($p_id=8);
    $data['kids']=$this->roxmodel->get_category_by_parent($p_id=9);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'men-'.$category;
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['uri_rsegment'] = 4;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->roxmodel->count_category_images($category_id);
    $data['galllery']=$this->roxmodel->get_gallery_men_images($category_id,$config['per_page'],$this->uri->rsegment(4));

    $this->load->library('pagination',$config);
    $data['page_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


    $this->load->view('men_clothing_image',$data);

}
```

Here is the model am passing

```
 public function get_category_id($category_name)
 {
  $this->db->select('category.id');
  $this->db->where('category.category_name',$category_name);
  $result = $this->db->get('category')->row();
  if($result)
  {
   return $result->id;
  }
}
```

i had done self join for connecting the id and category name but the output was null

```
public function get_category_id($category_name)
{
$this->db->select('c.id');
$this->db->join('category c1','c.id=c1.category_name');
$this->db->where('c1.category_name',$category_name);
$result = $this->db->get('category c')->row();
  if($result)
  {
    return $result->id;
  }
}
```

count image function as follows..

```
public function count_category_images($p_id)
{
  $this->db->select('gallery.*','category.category_name');
  $this->db->join('category', 'category.id = gallery.category_id');
  $this->db->where('category.id',$p_id);
  $this->db->order_by('gallery.id','desc');
  return $this->db->count_all_results('gallery');
}
```

Comment: where is the self join query ?

Comment: try my updated answers

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `result()` or `result_array()`. Because there are several rows in result.

`row()` - This function returns a **single result** row.

`result()` - This function returns the query result as an **array of objects**, or an **empty array on failure**.

So, try

```
public function get_category_id($category_name)
{
  $this->db->select('category.id');
  $this->db->join('category c1','c.id=c1.category_name');
  $this->db->where('category.category_name',$category_name);
  $result = $this->db->get('category')->result();

  return $result;
}
```

Also you can use

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
```

to check if there are rows.

If you use, search, and use part of category name, use `LIKE` interms of `WHERE`.

Comment: @MOHAMMED try to get array and analyze all of values

Comment: @MOHAMMED your main function is incorrent. query result is array, but you are using only first id.

Comment: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'  am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

try to use like query

If you want to control where the wildcard (%) is placed, you can use an optional third argument. Your options are 'before', 'after' and 'both'

and try group by

```
public function get_category_id($category_name)
 {
 $this->db->select('category.id');
 $this->db->like('category.category_name',$category_name,'both');
 $this->db->group_by(array("category.id", "category.category_name","category.parent_id")); 
 $result = $this->db->get('category')->result_array();
  if($result)
  {
    print_r($result);
    exit;
   // return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: comment the return $result->id;   print the $result->id; exit;

Comment: am getting the value 10

Comment: yes in   T-shirts    id is 10     so it returning 10 its right only na ?

Comment: but am getting id 10 for all

Comment: if you search men that is also returning 10  is it ??

Comment: the id returning for shirt under men category is 11 and same for shirt in kids category

Comment: the concept i understood but am getting an error like Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: getting error on count_category_images function i will post my count_category_images

Comment: THERE SELECT QUERY SHOULD BE LIKE THIS $this->db->select('gallery.*,category.category_name');

Comment: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `gallery` JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id` = `gallery`.`category_id` WHERE `category`.`id` = `Array` ORDER BY `gallery`.`id` DESC

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/rox/application/models/roxmodel.php

Line Number: 80

Comment: line no 80 is return $this->db->count_all_results('gallery');

Comment: PRINT $p_id INSIDE THE FUNCTION MAY BE IT EMPTY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112122/discussion-between-jothi-and-mohammed).

Comment: if $p_id is array means use $this->db->where_in('category.id', $p_id);

Comment: $p_id is not an array